# HTML tags (<br>, <hr> etc) are not rendering in table when using flask

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask

I have a json file with alternate product descriptions that I want to show to the end user. I try to make a table and show the two descriptions side by side for comparison. I have tried json2htm, I have tried creating a DF and converting to html table, and putting  {{ table | safe }} in the html, but I end up seeing 
 tags instead of line breaks. How do I fix this?

Here is my python file:

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, render_template, abort, url_for, Markup
import json
from json2html import Json2Html


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    desc1 = "This is an amazing product. <br> It will change your life forever. <br> In ways you can not imagine"
    desc2 = "This product will change your life. <br> Although we can't say for good or for bad. <br> It can either turn your life in heaven, or hell"
    
    table = pd.DataFrame({"Desc1":[desc1], "Desc2":[desc2]})
    ###table = pd.DataFrame({"RPD":["kuchh bhi"], "Generated":["kuchh bhi again"]})
    table = table.to_html(index=False)
    return render_template('inde.html', table=table)
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'css/style.css') }}">
    <title>Do Something</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Welcome to Doing something</h1>
   <div class="container"></div>
   <div>
      {{ table | safe }}
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z1FX.png)

I expected the table entries to be properly formatted, with each 
 to produce a line break.

Comment: This isn't anything to do with `flask`. It's `pandas` that is rendering the HTML

Comment: Basically, `pandas` has no idea that that text is HTML, so it will be displayed as a string. I don't ever use `pandas` to generate HTML for me, but that's where you need to be looking

Comment: Using `table = table.to_html(index=False, escape=False)` ought to solve the problem